# how to configure neo4j database on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I set up a neo4j database on ec2 and am not sure how to access it with my restclient.  Firstly, how do I change the username and password once its on ec2 and running?  Also, what do I change my localhost to so I can access the server?

This is the example statement I want to know how to configure:

```
from neo4jrestclient import client
db = client.GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474", username="neo4j", password="neo4j")
```

Comment: FYI there is a CloudFormation template that might make spinning up ec2 Neo4j instances easier: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/ec2neo for using

Comment: I set it up, but it's stuck on Rollback Complete

Comment: Ok I got it working, but I'm still wondering how to set up the client.

Comment: If you look in the outputs tab for the new stack in the CloudFormation console you should see `Neo4jEndPoint`. The default username and password is neo4j (for both username and password). You can change these by logging into the browser, which is the `Neo4jWebadmin` url in the CloudFormation console.

Comment: I keep getting this error even though I changed the file in "neo4j-server.properties":

py2neo.error.Unauthorized: http://localhost:7474/db/data/

Comment: my browser works fine, but it won't work in a script.

Answer (score 0):

The first action you have to do on a new neo4j instance is changing the password. To do so use your browser and connect to the db using http://:7474. Use default login neo4j/neo4j and change your pw.

Your client app then of course needs to supply the changed password.

Alternatively you can change the pw by REST API as sell, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-security-user-status-and-password-changing.

Comment: It's weird, my password is right, my user account is right, but when I try to use py2neo, I input this and get the following error:


authenticate("xx.x.xx.xx:7474", "neo4j", "xxxxx")
graph = Graph("http://neo4j:%s@xx.x.xx.xx:7474" %('xxxxx'))


py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: timed out

Comment: I think part of the problem is my endpoints don't have ":7474" in them, they're just xx.x.xx.xx